# MSI InstallValidate FilesInUse over-active on shell extension?

Tags: shell, windows-installer, explorer

I am using [Advanced Installer (MSI)](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) to install a shell extension DLL for an explorer context menu. This works except on Uninstall Custom Action in InstallExecuteSequence I had to add a command to regsvr32.exe /s /u in order to de-register the DLL.

The problem I have is that upon subsequent re-installs of the same product (with a different Product Version and Product code) so that there is an first an automatic uninstallation of the app, sometimes explorer does not release the DLL which causes the FilesInUse box to appear and prompt to kill Explorer.exe or reboot the machine.

Because the shell extension has no bugs and does not need to be replaced, and because I have not upgraded its version number in between installs, I wish to avoid re-installing it or checking if it is in use unless its version has changed.

I have attempted to add a Search for the file in MSI in [APPDIR] but all that returns is "C:\" although the file is actually somewhere else in the appdir folder

Is there an easy way to skip reinstallation of the file if it already exists and to skip the InstallValidate for FilesInUse?

Answer (score 1):

You might try to set the condition on your custom action to consider the component state as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx

Since you're not updating version of the file and assuming it's component's keypath, Windows Installer should not attempt to reinstall the component. In this case, condition like this have big chance to work:
$ComponentId=3
where ComponentId is identifier of component owning your shell extension. With this condition, your CA should be executed only when component "ComponentId" is actually (re)installed.